# Need help with recursion in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am representing a tree in a table, and I need to be able to get the root node (`TOP ID`) of a specific element.  The root node always has a `ParentID` of `null`.  For example, if the table looks like this:

```
ID   ParentID
1   null
2   null
3   null
4   2
5   1
6   2
7   6
8   4
9   8
10  6
```

When `ID=10`, the `TOP ID = 2`; when `ID=9`, the `TOP ID = 3`; and so on.  Is it possible to write a SQL server function, which returns `TOP ID` when given `ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion in SQL prior to SQL 2003 (i.e. SQL Server 2000) is somewhat ugly; for each level in your tree you'd need to write a separate join statement back onto the original table. Provided that the number of levels in your hierarchy is fixed you could write something like this.

```
create table #Hell (
parent int,
id int,
name varchar(30)
)

insert into #Hell values (NULL, 1, 'The Boss')
insert into #Hell values (1, 2, 'The Boss'' PA')
insert into #Hell values (1, 3, 'Production Director')
insert into #Hell values (3, 4, 'Jim''l Fixit')


select * from #Hell H1
inner join #Hell H2
ON H1.id=H2.parent
inner join #Hell H3
ON H2.id=H3.parent
WHERE H3.Id=4  --Find the boss for Jim

drop table #Hell
```

Luckily SQL Server 2005 has a **with** common table expression that allows recursive operations to be written quite easily. See See https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml

You should also be aware of the various ways of representing trees in a database. Take a look at the slides on Trees in SQL from this presentation http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back

Comment: That "with" operator is actually called a "Common Table Expression" (CTE) and it's not a SQL Server specific extension, but it's part of the SQL:2003 Standard.

Comment: Thanks for some reason I thought it was a Microsoft thing but looking around Postgres also supports CTEs using WITH RECURSIVE.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a recursive example from a sproc I have that will find the Parent (parent ID = null) for any given ID - (@ID) given to the sproc.  Is this whaat you're looking for?

```
    WITH recurseUp (ID, ParentID)
    AS
    (
        SELECT ID, ParentID
        FROM myTable
        WHERE ID = @ID 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT b.ID, b.ParentID
        FROM recurseUp a JOIN myTable b 
        ON (a.ParentID = b.ID)
    )
SELECT ID FROM recurseUP WHERE ParentID is null
```

Comment: This example works good, but how to put all this thing into View or sql Function, is it imposible?

Answer (score 2):

MSDN has a pretty good set of examples for using [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) to write recursive queries. It was a big pain in the rear to do these prior to SQL Server 2005 (dealing with that exact problem in an old Server 2000 app right now).

Answer (score 0):

MSDN brough up [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175801(SQL.80).aspx) which will most likely explain it better than you are likely to get in the format we are allowed on this sight.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but the only method I know is to use a CURSOR and a recursive stored procedure.  This is a really bad way to do things from a performance standpoint (usually).  If possible you may want to consider the cost of having an extra root parent node that you keep updated via code as you move along.

Comment: CTE's make the process so much easier now in server 2005 and beyond. It is in fact a P.I.T.A. for Sever 2000

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  id, parentID
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   id = 10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  mytable.id, mytable.parentid
        FROM    q
        JOIN    mytable
        ON      mytable.parentId = q.id
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
WHERE   parentID IS NULL
```